# How do I add a class to the parent of an element whose height is greater than it's width

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

On the Wordpress site I am working on I need to add a class of 'tall' to all portrait images so they have padding. All other images would get the class of 'wide'. The images have captions which also need to be included in the padding, and so it is actually the `<figure>` parent element I need to add the class of 'tall' to, rather than the `<img>` tag. So I am trying to add a class to all `<figure>` elements which have a child `<img>` whose height is greater than its width.

My problem is that whilst the `<img>` has height and width specified, `<figure>` only has height, and so the following code results in a class of 'wide' being added to all images as I'm guessing it is just getting the width from the `<figure>` elements with no height to compare it to, when it should be getting the height and width from the `<img>` elements.

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    jQuery('img').parent().addClass(function() {
        if (this.height > this.width) {
            return 'tall';
        } else {
            return 'wide';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

How would I correct my code to add a class of 'tall' to all `<figure>` elements which contain an `<img>` element whose height is greater than its width?

Comment: height and width is not referencing the image, it is the parent.

Comment: Thank you, so how do I make height and width reference the image, and still have the class added to the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `.find()` the image again inside the function, as `this` will point to the parent. Also if there are multiple images on the page you will probably need to wrap it in an `.each()` loop to call it on every instance of `img` and their respective parents.

```
jQuery('img').each(function(index, element) {
    jQuery(element).parent().addClass(function() {
            let img = jQuery(this).find('img');
            if (img.height() > img.width()) {
                return 'tall';
            } else {
                return 'wide';
            }
        });
});
```

Note: this will mark 1:1 ratio images as 'wide'

#### Edit:

If you're using `each` this is a lot more efficient and straightforward:

```
jQuery('img').each(function(index, element) {
    let img = jQuery(element);
    let width = img.width();
    let height = img.height();
    let cls = width > height ? 'wide':'tall';

    img.parent().addClass(cls);
});
```

Comment: @NPC welcome, check the edit, I just realized my initial answer is a bit overcomplicated

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code. you have to find img height and width under .

jQuery('figure img').each(function () {

```
    if(jQuery(this).height() > jQuery(this).width())
    {
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('tall');
        }
    else{
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('wide');

        }
    });
```